# Running a rails app on an internal network with access to an external form possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a rails project that will be deployed on an internal network for large businesses. It will be for internal use only. However, one of the feature requirements for this project is that external non-users can receive an email with a url/token that takes them to a form to supply information to the application's database from outside the network. What would be the best way, or is it even possible, to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to be internal only you should create another app in the same network that has external visibility, and you can communicate with your internal app between the two, maybe through an API.

hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Yes, we are leaning in this direction, though it would be great to keep it as one app. What are you're thoughts on Nathan's approach?

Comment: Yes that is a good solution also, but in my mind I though you wanted 0 access from external requests. maybe for security purposes you don't want any outside traffic on that server, if that's not the case Nathan's solution is even better and tighter than mine.

Comment: Actually, 0 access may be necessary in this case. I think what we may do, is have the external part hosted as a separate app in a dmz, that would then connect to the internal app database through a hole in the firewall.

Comment: if 0 access is the way to go then 2 apps through a DMZ sounds good. hope I helped. have a good one !

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to limit access to any given route or controller action from within the Rails project (the Rack request object contains the IP that generated the request), but a better way would be to leverage features in your reverse proxy.  If you're using nginx, see [this page](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/).  You should be able to set something up like this in your nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    allow 192.168.1.1/24; # or whatever IP range you want to permit through
    allow 127.0.0.1;      # for local development
    deny all;             # block everyone else
    ... # the reset of your app config
}

location /path-to-external-form {
    allow all;
}
```

Of course, it might be easier to stand up a separate app and just share a database

Comment: Thank you! Yes, we are leaning towards two separate applications, but it would be preferable to do something like this. I am going to do some more research but thanks again!